# What does it reveal if someone laps water like dogs?

Tags: judges

In Judges 7:5 (NASB)

> So he brought the people down to the water. Then the Lord said to Gideon, “You shall put everyone who **laps the water with his tongue as a dog laps** in one group, and everyone who kneels down to drink in another.”

What does it reveal if someone drinks water in this matter?

This question isn't the same as [this one](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/21143/27054) (which doesn't even have an accepted answer). Here I want to know what such behaviour reveals from the context of when it was written. The other question asks why is it significant to separate them based on that and why 300 persons (two questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinction between the two groups in Judges 7:5 concerned those who were prepared to move quickly a decisively.

- Those who lapped like a dog were those who remained alert and did not delay - they remained ready for battle and to receive orders.
- Those who knelt down to drink were those who took their time and could be distracted from the matter at hand.

Thus, the simple test separated those men who would make good, focused soldiers who responded promptly to orders and the battle situation.

Matthew Poole arrives at a similar conclusion:

> the true reason and design of this course seems to be only this, that
> God would reduce them to a very small number, which was likely to be
> done by this means; for the season of the year being hot, and the
> generality of the soldiers weary, and thirsty, and faint, they would
> most probably bow down upon their knees, that they might more fully
> refresh themselves by a liberal draught, as indeed they did; and it
> could be expected that there would be but few, who either could or
> would deny themselves in this matter, especially when God concurred in
> the work, and so disposed of the minds and bodies of them, that all,
> except three hundred, should lie down to drink.

Comment: I'm sceptical about this - what in the text makes alertness relevant? I think the primary point was to select a ridiculously tiny group (by human standards) for God to do his work through. The whole point was to reduce any opportunity for Israel to boast, so if the lapping indicates the super soldiers then that doesn't help.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I agree - but that was the divine method chosen to get the ridiculously small group on a hot day.

Comment: It was the method, but I disagree with the motives you've assigned to God.

Comment: @Dottard I can imagine "Those who lapped like a dog were those who remained alert and did not delay" to be people that give everything to the point of having to drink water like a dog and even then when all other muscles are tired they still move the tongue to drink the water.